# Plugin/Folder permission issues with Azure

Tags: plugins, permissions

Has anyone come across plugin issues when using Wordpress with Azure?

I recently spun up a free wordpress install on azurewebsites.net, using PHP 5.4 and Wordpress 3.5.

Once plugin in particualr, WPTouch seems to be having issues when creating a folder or uploading a file.

Has anyone else had an issues whhere a plugin is failing due to folder permissons?

Comment: Your description on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236459/folder-permissions-for-wordpress-on-azure) is much better than this one. I commented there.